# How to split long execution time functions on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Let's say I have function A, B, C, D, all of them are not exceed the execution time limit of Firebase Cloud Functions. But if at the end of function A it calls function B, at the end of function B, it calls function C ... and so on, like below:

```
function A(): Promise {
    doStuffA()
    return httpPostFunctionB()
}

function B(): Promise {
    doStuffB()
    return httpPostFunctionC()
}

function C(): Promise {
    doStuffC()
    return httpPostFunctionD()
}

function D() {
    doStuffD()
}
```

All together it will exceed the time limit.

Is there any way to make function A no need to wait for function B, but also guarantee function B will be executed completely?

I think it is possible, we can just make function A modify some value in Firestore, and make function B listen to that value change. But I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: It sounds like function B actually just needs to wait until after A finishes, if it need the work with the results.  I'm not sure why you're proposing to make them run in parallel and have B "listen" the the result of "A".

Comment: The idea is they are 4 parts of one big function, I separate them into 4 different part so each wont exceed the time limit. The result of A() is just a dummy variable I use to trigger B(). Otherwise I don't know how to trigger B() after A() is finished() without making A() wait for B() and exceed the time limit.

Comment: What is the time limit?  If you need more processing time than is allowed by Cloud Functions, then that product might not be right for you.  Perhaps App Engine or Compute Engine will be better, since they can process batch jobs with no real time limit.

Comment: I can move the heavy part to compute engine, but since I need the Firebase authentication stuff, so the API still need to be Cloud Functions. While the API waiting for the compute engine to respond. It will exceed the cloud function time limit.

Comment: Again, what is the time limit?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: 1 minute by default, can expand to roughly 10 minutes maximum. After the the time limit, function will be aborted and return an error status code.

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the timeout for Cloud Functions.  The default of 1 minute can be extended up to 9 minutes.  Please [read the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout) about that.

If you need more than 9 minutes, you'll need to consider delegating the work to a service that doesn't have strict restrictions, such as App Engine or Compute Engine.  But the 9 minute limit for Cloud Functions can't be changed.